# DataSet Merge with ignore case senstivity

Tags: c#, postgresql, xsd, dataset

We are working on an existing application that uses SQL Server. And now we migrated the SQL Server database from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL has all the table names and their columns to lower case. But we are still using the same code which we used for SQL Server.

Now we have existing XSD related files which was generated for SQL Server database. The XSD file is having the camel case for table names and column names. Now that we are using Postgres to connect to the server, the existing SQL queries are working properly. But the following code failed due to case sensitive issue.

Method:

```
     public DataSet getMKey() {
        string sql = "SELECT * from MInfo where id=1";
        -- code to return dataset.
        return dataset;
     }
```

Code:

```
        DataSet ds1 = dbMgr.getMKey();

        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        ds2.Tables.Add(XSDSchema.MInfo.Copy());
        ds1.Merge(ds2);
```

The Merge() method failed saying, System.Data.DataException
  HResult=0x80131920
  Message=Mismatch columns in the PrimaryKey : .m_key versus .M_Key.

Can someone please suggest me a solution without changing the XSD file.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This is not a Postgres issue. As far a case Postgres is not case sensitive as far as table or column names are concerned. Yes they are translated internally to lower case, but to Postgres the columns m_key and M_Key are the same thing. To have kept case they would have to be double quoted ( so "M_Key" but then it must always be quoted that way). Further that is not a Postgres message it would have just indicated 'invalid identifier'. The problem then lies within your c# or XSD processor.

Comment: @Belayer Thanks, yes, the problem here is in the XSD. The XSD file has the mixed case and DataSet.merge() method failed. We don't want to change the XSD file as this is existing working project. So we are making changes to existing code as and when it is required. Do you think regenerating the XSD is the only solution.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. As far as regenerating XSD I am not familiar with it so I really don't know.  I couldn't tell where the problem was, just knew where it was not. Glad you found it.